# Log out from vbulletin and changed template

Tags: templates, logout, vbulletin

my question: When i log out from vbulletin, my template is changed to default. why is it? thanks who answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your custom style can`t be used by guests. Check next items:

1. Set your custom style as the default style:
   ACP - vBulletin Options - vBulletin Options - Style & Language Settings - Allow Users To Change Styles - Default Style
2. Be shure users can change styles if you need this:
   ACP - vBulletin Options - vBulletin Options - Style & Language Settings - Allow Users To Change Styles - Yes
3. Be shure that your custom style checked here: 
   ACP - Styles & Templates - Style Manager

Comment: Thanks i find in what problem, maybe in this.
ACP - vBulletin Options - vBulletin Options - Style & Language Settings - Allow Users To Change Styles - Default Style
there set "default style" "Select the default style for your forums. This style will be used for all guests, and any members who have not expressed a style preference in their options, or are attempting to use a style that does not exist or is forbidden."
I must to set my template.